# How could I conduct meta-analysis on percentage outcomes using R?

Tags: r

My example data is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(study = c("Hodaie","Kerrigan","Lee","Andrade","Lim"), SR = c(0.5460, 0.2270, 0.7540, 0.6420, 0.5000), SE = c(12.30, 15.70, 12.80, 13.80, 9.00), Patients = c(5, 5, 3, 6, 4))
```

I want to conduct the meta-analysis with SR(single group percentage), SE (standard error that I can compute based on sample size and percentage), and patients(sample size for each study), and I hope I could get the following forest plot (I found this example in an article, and they also have one group percentage data, but I can't find which R statement or argument they used):

[image: Example forest plot with single group percentage outcome]

Could anyone tell me which R statement or argument that I could use to conduct the meta-analysis and generate the forest plot above? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just to note, you will get much more detailed and helpful advice faster if you post code that provides sample data.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could post code that provides sample data, but I didn't find the code, that why I am asking which code that I should use. I've been struggling for weeks.

Comment: Sure - and to clarify, I was talking about sample data, not code to create the desired output. You can create sample data yourself, i.e., `df <- data.frame(study = c("A","B","C"), OR = c(0.9, 0.8, 1.4), ci_lo = c(0.2, 0.4, 1.0), ci_hi = c(1.1, 1.2, 2.2))` Make it as similar to your data as possible (for instance, write the first five lines of the image in code), then people can help you manipulate it to make the desired output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just edited it, hopefully, it will look good, thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are plenty of ways to do this using packages but it can be accomplished in base R (and there are likely more elegant solutions using base R). The way I do it is to first build a blank plot much larger than the needed graphing portion, then overlay the relevant elements on it. I find one has more control over it this way. A basic example that could get you started is below. If you are new to R (based on your name NewRUser), I suggest running it line-by-line to see how it all works. Again, this is only one way and there are likely better approaches. Good luck!

##### Sample Data

```
#### Sample Data (modified from OP)
df <- data.frame(Study = c("Hodaie","Kerrigan","Lee","Andrade","Lim"), 
                 SR = c(0.5460, 0.2270, 0.7540, 0.6420, 0.5000), 
                 SE = c(12.30, 15.70, 12.80, 13.80, 9.00), 
                 Patients = c(5, 5, 3, 6, 4),
                 ci_lo = c(30, -8.0, 50, 37, 32),
                 ci_hi = c(78, 53, 100, 91, 67))
```

```
### Set up plotting elements
n.studies <- nrow(df)
yy <- n.studies:1
seqx <- seq(-100, 100, 50)

## blank plot much larger than needed
plot(range(-550, 200), range(0, n.studies), type = 'n', axes = F, xlab = '', ylab = '') #blank plot, much bigger than plotting portion needed
  
# Set up axes
  axis(side = 1, at = seqx, labels = seqx, cex.axis = 1, mgp = c(2, 1.5, 1)) # add axis and label (bottom)
  mtext(side = 1, at = 0, 'Seizure Reduction', line = 2.5, cex = 0.85, padj = 1) 
  axis(side = 3, at = seqx, labels = seqx, cex.axis = 1, mgp = c(2, 1.5, 1)) # add axis and label (top)
  mtext(side = 3, at = 0, 'Seizure Reduction', line = 2.5, cex = 0.85, padj = -1) 

## add lines and dots
 segments(df[, "ci_lo"], yy, df[,"ci_hi"], yy) # add lines
   points(df[,"SR"]*100, yy, pch = 19) # add points
   segments(x0 = 0, y0 = max(yy), y1 = 0, lty = 3, lwd = 0.75) #vertical line @ 0

### Add text information
  
 par(xpd = TRUE) 
  text(x = -550, y = yy, df[,"Study"], pos = 4)
  text(x = -450, y = yy, df[,"SR"]*100, pos = 4)
  text(x = -350, y = yy, df[,"SE"], pos = 4)
  text(x = -250, y = yy, df[,"Patients"], pos = 4)
  text(x = 150, y = yy, paste0(df[,"ci_lo"], "-", df[,"ci_hi"]), pos = 4)
  text(x = c(seq(-550, -250, 100), 150), y = max(yy)+0.75, 
       c(colnames(df)[1:4], "CI"), pos = 4, font = 2)

# Add legend
  legend(x = 50, y = 0.5, c("Point estimate", "95% Confidence interval"), 
         pch = c(19, NA), lty = c(NA, 19), bty = "n", cex = 0.65)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for taking the time to type all this, but I guess my question is misleading. I want to conduct meta-analysis with r packages like meta or metafor, and after the data were analyzed, we can use "forest" statement to generate the forest plot with the random effects model and heterogeneity blow the example graph that I posted. I am so sorry about the confusing. So, do you know which r package and r argument that I should use to do this?